# Make sure http connection is over wifi

Tags: android, wifi

I have a small service on app that gathers data during the day, and saves the data to sd card. A premise is that data will be large, so app should under no circumstances upload that data over users' data plan.

There are situations where wifi 'exists' but is unusable, and phone routes network requests as best as it can, using data plan connection if it can.

Is there a way, however dirty, to ensure that request will pass wifi connection ONLY or FAIL otherwise?

EDIT:

By reading my question I discovered that I didn't explain in detail what's going on.  I'm gathering data from the environment (some form of logging) and that data accumulates on SD card.  When user is near or at home (or any other WiFi enabled place) software should detect that and dequeue sd card contents through http POST requests.  Files are 1MB or more in size, so even if I detect the presence of Wifi, it can change during transfer.  Or worse, Wifi can be ON, but un-routable, so telephone routes the connection through your data plan, and ruins your budget for the month.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with two things:

1- Before you upload, chech that currently the mobile is connected via Wi-Fi, here is an example function

```
 public static boolean isConnectedToWiFi(Context context) {
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = getConnectivityManager(context)
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null) {
        return activeNetwork.isConnected()
                && activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
    }
    return false;
}
```

2- Listen to connectivity change broadcase `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` to monitor when the connection is changing e.g. switching to 3G